# WIX: Windows Service Repair failing on lack of permissions + how to detecting repair mode?

Tags: c#, wix, installation, wix3.5

Our WIX setup installs a windows service after asking logon account through a custom UI dialog..
The service starts after installation succeeds.
Entire setup requires elevated privileges.

Hoping for any pointers regarding couple of questions:

**Question 1**
On attempting  "Repair" from "Add/Remove Programs", UAC  prompts for  privilege elevation. After allowing so, the repair still fails with message:

"Service  could not be installed. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to install system services".

Here's excerpt from code:

...

Privileged
 ...

```
  <Component Id="C_ServiceEXE" Guid="{105F9C86-BF07-43C8-8C78-DF30F012CD68}">
    <File Id="$(var.TargetFileName)" Name="$(var.TargetFileName)" KeyPath="yes"  Assembly=".net"
          AssemblyManifest="$(var.TargetFileName)" AssemblyApplication="$(var.TargetFileName)" DiskId="1"
          Source="$(var.TargetDir)\$(var.TargetFileName)" />

    <Condition>Privileged</Condition>

    <ServiceInstall Id="Id_ServiceInstall"
                     Name ="$(var.ServiceName)"
                     Description="$(var.ServiceDescription)"
                     DisplayName="$(var.ServiceName)"
                     Account="[SERVICEACCOUNT]"
                     Password="[SERVICEPASSWORD]"
                     Start="auto"
                     ErrorControl="normal"
                     Type="ownProcess"
                     Vital="yes"
                     Interactive="no"
                     />

    <ServiceControl Id="Id_ServiceControl"
                    Name ="$(var.ServiceName)"
                     Remove="uninstall"
                     Start="install"
                     Stop="both"
                     Wait="yes"
                    />

  </Component>
```

...

I not quite sure why this is happening, since I admin am on on my Win7 dev box and have marked both the setup and speicifically the service install component to be run in privileged mode.

I suspect I might be missing scheduling repair inside an AdminInstallExecute sequence but not quite sure if that will fix this.

**Question 2**
Also, related question is - if repair does succeed, would it again require user to enter logon account via the UI.
I'd rather suppress all interactive UIs during repair or upgrade. I realize that UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE to detect upgrade.

But how is repair detected ?

Appreciate any help or pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Maintenance mode most likely fails because your service user account doesn't have the right to [log on as a service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739424%28WS.10%29.aspx). It doesn't matter if you are an Administrator, you cannot install services for an user without giving him the log on right.

If setting this policy works, you also need to do it dynamically during install. A solution is to use [ntrights.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315276) as a custom action. This custom action can use your custom properties which contains the user account information.

To detect a repair process, you can check the [REINSTALL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371175%28VS.85%29.aspx) property value.

Comment: Should have mentioned I am building setup for Vista onwards. On Windows 7 when installing a service using installUtil.exe, the logon right is automatically awarded to the service account specified. (need to check the same on vista).

Comment: The problem seems a repair/reinstall is a like new install (dunno if installer first uninstalls). On repair, my UI that asks for logon account does not show up, causing SERVICEACCOUNT unintialized to some default blah value. This causes service installation to fail, leading to repair/reinstall failure. _Thanks for your response._ NTrights.exe seems targeted for older OS versions, should have said I am targeting Vista onwards where this utility doesn't see to be present (I could be missing something).

Comment: In your code sample you are using ServiceInstall and ServiceControl tables. So you need to set the log on as a service policy like I explained. "ntrights.exe" works on Vista and Windows 7 as long as the custom action which executes it is deferred with no impersonation.